# Dynamic error handling messages in slider revolution plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using slider revolution wordpress plugin to show youtube videos in my website sliders,

and sometimes due to youtube blocked or can't be loaded it show this error

```
YouTube Api Could not be loaded
```

and i saw that it is hard coded in the minified JS file of the plugin

is there a way to customize the message from the admin panel, it's my first time to use wordpress and to use this plugin.

Thank you